# DbContext has no data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my MVC5 project I created a DbContext with the connectionString to my local server. SaveChanges actually works and saves the data to the database, but when I'm trying to use the context to use the saved data, it's lists are empty.
The context:

```
public class DbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DbContext(string connString) : base(connString) { }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public virtual DbSet<JobSeeker> JobSeekers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

The Web.config file:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The controller I'm using it in:

```
using (DbContext _context = new DbContext("name = DefaultConnection"))
{
    var x = _context.Database.Connection.State; // x is "Closed"
    viewModel.JobSeeker = _context.JobSeekers.First(j => j.Id == user.JobSeekerId); //JobSeekers is empty
}
```

The JobSeekers list is empty even though there are in the database.

Okay so I'm trying to figure this out. I'M getting some data back if I do this:

```
var list = _context.JobSeekers.Include("Tags");
```

And after this line, the _context has JobSeekers in it, just not all of them.
SO how can I load all of the data at once into the context?

Comment: Is your `DbContext` initializing a new database each time you use it? Can you query the database and indeed see that there is data?

Comment: See my answer under Tugbay Atilla. WHen running the query on the database I do get back data, but the context does not return data.

Comment: If nothing is being returned, nothing is being matched by your query. Check the query and check your database. One of the two doesn't match up.